# undefined reference to public methods/variables of a class

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I have a linker problem between 2 files F1 and F2. In order to be more readable, I rewrote the code and output.

F1.h:

```
class MYCLASS...
   public:....// [constructor] etc         
         void myMethod(const string& r);
         static string s;
```

F1.cpp:

```
void myMethod(const string& r)
{
    MYCLASS::s=r;
}
[...]
void serialize(...)
{
   operation(s,...)
}
```

F2.cpp:

```
const string& a;
MYCLASS Obj;
Obj.myMethod(a);
```

The goal is to use the string a from F2.cpp inside the serialize method from F1.cpp, without adding any argument to the serialize function. For that, I am trying to use the intermediate r variable.

The compilation (compiler based on gcc) gives the errors:

```
In function `the_function_from_F2.cpp(...)':
F2.cpp:227: undefined reference to `MYCLASS::myMethod(std::basic_string<char,      std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
: In function `myMethod(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,   std::allocator<char> > const&)':
F1.cpp:197: undefined reference to `MYCLASS::s'
: In function `MYCLASS::serialize(....) const':
F2.cpp:69: undefined reference to `MYCLASS::s'
```

Thank you for any suggestion !

Comment: Remember to add on top of *F2.cpp*: **std::string MYCLASS::s;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
void MYCLASS::myMethod(const string& r)
{
    MYCLASS::s=r;
}

std::string MYCLASS::s;
```

This is still a class method, so you need to specify that.

Comment: They will also need to define the `static` data member `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually *define* the `MYCLASS::s` member. It has to be done in a source file like

```
std::string MYCLASS::s;
```

What you are doing in the class is only *declaring* the static variable.

Comment: I solved. In the .h I have the declaration with static and in the .cpp i have the definition without static. Thank you.